# Expanding sum with group by date

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe where I'm trying to do an expanding sum of values and group them by date.

Specifically, my data looks like:

```
creationDateTime    OK  Fail    
2017-01-06 21:30:00 4   0
2017-01-06 21:35:00 4   0
2017-01-06 21:36:00 4   0

2017-01-07 21:48:00 3   1
2017-01-07 21:53:00 4   0

2017-01-08 21:22:00 3   1
2017-01-08 21:27:00 3   1

2017-01-09 21:49:00 3   1
```

and I'm trying to get something similar to:

```
creationDateTime    OK  Fail  RollingOK  RollingFail
2017-01-06 21:30:00 4   0     4          0
2017-01-06 21:35:00 4   0     8          0
2017-01-06 21:36:00 4   0     12         0

2017-01-07 21:48:00 3   1     3          1
2017-01-07 21:53:00 4   0     7          1

2017-01-08 21:22:00 3   1     3          1
2017-01-08 21:27:00 3   1     6          2

2017-01-09 21:49:00 3   1     3          1
```

I've figured out how to do a rolling sum of the values by using:

```
data_aggregated['RollingOK'] = data_aggregated['OK'].expanding(0).sum()       
data_aggregated['RollingFail'] = data_aggregated['Fail'].expanding(0).sum()
```

But I'm not sure how I can alter this to get the rolling sums grouped by day, since the code above does a rolling sum over all the rows, without grouping by day.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: There is `DatetimeIndex` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum.html) with specified columns after `groupby`:

```
#if DatetimeIndex
idx = data_aggregated.index.date
#if column
#idx = data_aggregated['creationDateTime'].dt.date
data_aggregated[['RollingOK','RollingFail']] = (data_aggregated.groupby(idx)['OK','Fail']
                                                               .cumsum())
print (data_aggregated)
                     OK  Fail  RollingOK  RollingFail
creationDateTime                                     
2017-01-06 21:30:00   4     0          4            0
2017-01-06 21:35:00   4     0          8            0
2017-01-06 21:36:00   4     0         12            0
2017-01-07 21:48:00   3     1          3            1
2017-01-07 21:53:00   4     0          7            1
2017-01-08 21:22:00   3     1          3            1
2017-01-08 21:27:00   3     1          6            2
2017-01-09 21:49:00   3     1          3            1
```

You can also working with all columns:

```
data_aggregated = (data_aggregated.join(data_aggregated.groupby(idx)
                                                       .cumsum()
                                                       .add_prefix('Rolling')))
print (data_aggregated)
                     OK  Fail  RollingOK  RollingFail
creationDateTime                                     
2017-01-06 21:30:00   4     0          4            0
2017-01-06 21:35:00   4     0          8            0
2017-01-06 21:36:00   4     0         12            0
2017-01-07 21:48:00   3     1          3            1
2017-01-07 21:53:00   4     0          7            1
2017-01-08 21:22:00   3     1          3            1
2017-01-08 21:27:00   3     1          6            2
2017-01-09 21:49:00   3     1          3            1
```

Your solution should be changed:

```
data_aggregated[['RollingOK','RollingFail']] = (data_aggregated.groupby(idx)['OK','Fail']
                                                           .expanding(0)
                                                           .sum()
                                                           .reset_index(level=0, drop=True))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use, (if 1st column : `creationDateTime` is a column):

```
df['RollingOK']=df.groupby(df.creationDateTime.dt.date)['OK'].cumsum()
df['RollingFail']=df.groupby(df.creationDateTime.dt.date)['Fail'].cumsum()
print(df)

    creationDateTime  OK  Fail  RollingOK  RollingFail
0 2017-01-06 21:30:00  4   0     4          0          
1 2017-01-06 21:35:00  4   0     8          0          
2 2017-01-06 21:36:00  4   0     12         0          
3 2017-01-07 21:48:00  3   1     3          1          
4 2017-01-07 21:53:00  4   0     7          1          
5 2017-01-08 21:22:00  3   1     3          1          
6 2017-01-08 21:27:00  3   1     6          2          
7 2017-01-09 21:49:00  3   1     3          1
```